# Catching an OSError for keyboard module on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi-zero

I have build a RGB LED Matrix display that I am controlling with an 8BitDo Zero controller in Keyboard mode. To that end, I am using the Keyboard module in Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi Zero.

The controller shows up as a physical keyboard and works well to trigger different displays and such, however there is an issue that after a set amount of no inputs (10 Minutes) the controller will shut down and disappears from the device list, causing the keyboard module to throw an exception:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
Start button pressed in on state
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 106, in start_reading
    self.event_queue.put(device.read_event())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 83, in read_event
    data = self.input_file.read(struct.calcsize(event_bin_format))
OSError: [Errno 19] No such device
```

I have tried catching this error by wrapping the keyboard.wait() function in a try/except block, but unfortunately still have the thread crash without ever catching the exception.

```
def listen_for_button_presses():
    print("Waiting for button presses")
    try:
        keyboard.wait()
    except:
        print("Exception thrown! " + str(e))
```

I would basically like the python program to just ignore the presence of the keyboard here, and continue working as usual on the main thread if it is removed. Upon re-appearing, it'd be nice if it reacted to the key presses once more however.

Aside from a python solution, I'd also be happy with some kind of linux solution, such as a virtual keyboard the bluetooth keyboard's inputs are piped into, but that doesn't disappear on disconnect. The Pi is running DietPi, which is based on Debian

Thanks for the help!